# C language: is it bad to define functions in .c files which are not declared in .h files?

Tags: c

I have a function declared in .h file.

```
void func1();
```

In .c file apart from func1 I define func2 and use it in definition of func1 (func2 is NOT declared in .h file)

```
void func2()
{
   do something;
}

void func1()
{
   func2();
   do something else;
}
```

Why I do this is because I don't want to put declaration of func2 in .h file (this function wouldn't be used outside the module). So yeah, I want to create kind of "private" function in C.
My questions are: Is this a bad practice? Is there another way to create "private" functions in modules in C?

Comment: No, and you can even place your function declaration separately at the top of the .c file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not bad  `main()` being a prime example.

however if the function is not defined in an header file it's only properly callable from the .c file itself, and so should be declared `static`

```
static void func2()
{
   do something;
}
```

making it static will make it unavailable to external callers (so, you can't make main() static)

To police this pattern there's a `gcc` option to warn about non-static functions not previously prototyped
`-Wmissing-prototypes`

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfectly fine practice that is used a lot. This is indeed used to cretae a kind of "private" function. When doing this you normally also declare the function as static, eg.:

```
static void func2()
{
   do something;
}
```

That way the function is only available for use by code from this c file. Otherwise you can still use the function in another file if you know the prototype.